# How and Why is this If condition satisfying when value is false in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, if-statement, visual-studio-2013, and-operator

I have this strange problem in Windows Phone Application. Hitting hardware Back button exits the application when it should have shown the previous page. While debugging, I found something really strange.

[image: If Condition satisfied for false]

In this method, `this.Frame` is `Not null` (as shown in 3rd pin) but `this.Frame.CanGoBack is False` (as shown in 1st pin) which means the && (AND) operator should make this condition as `false` and it does (as shown in the second Pin). Still debugger stepped in the condition to execute(as you can see below second pin).

This is really strange and This only exits my application.

Comment: While debugging inside GoBack, keep pressing F11 (Step Into) to see whether the call is actually being made. Also are you debugging in Debug or Release mode?

Comment: @Rouby Sorry my bad.

Comment: @HadiBrais Debuggng in Debug mode. also it goes and execute the GoBack Statement

Comment: What template is this? Maybe we can try and recreate the behavior?

Comment: Visual-Studio 2013-> New Project-> C# -> Store App-> Windows Phone App -> Hub App-> Common Folder in Solution Explorer-> NavigationHelper.cs File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The this.Frame.CanGoBack property changed between the time it entered and the time it got to the next line.  A property that is implemented like the following:

```
get {
   var result=backingvalue;
   backingvalue=!result;
   return result;
}
```

Would do it.

Try changing the code to the following:

```
var bool1=this.Frame!=null;
if (bool1)
{
  var bool2=this.Frame.CanGoBack;
  if (bool2)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then put a breakpoint and check the values of bool1/bool2 as well as this.Frame.CanGoBack.

Comment: I think This might be the case but there is another problem. I tried adding a watch at CanGoBack property and visual studio said that its not a property. CanGoBack() is a Method and putting it to watch was not valid in the given context. Now how it compiled in the first place just by writing  this.Frame.CanGoBack instead of this.Frame.CanGoBack()

Comment: And Again when I put () symbol after this.Frame.CanGoBack, it gives compilation error as Error Non-invocable member 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.CanGoBack' cannot be used like a method. Now its getting on my nerves.

Comment: It is a read-only property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.cangoback.aspx which apparently checks the navigation history.  Is there another thread perhaps that can modify the navigation history?

Comment: I Think there was. To test the issue I tried with different pages and later on found that the issue was coming from my silly mistake. I had implemented my own handler for hardware back button event in the root page to close the application instead of sending in background. Later on I found that handler was already there in Navigation Helper class. So I guess both of them were executed simultaneously(Pretty Strange huh?!!) creating the strange situation. I removed my implementation and problem solved!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons:

Likely:
The property gets read multiple times and can return different values when it is first evaluated in the program and when it is watched in the Debugger. Does your application use multi-threading or oes the property usually change over time?

Unlikely:
A bug in the jit-compiler. Although this is extremely unlikely, people have stumbled upon these type of bug before.

Comment: Third: the value got changed by a different thread between the time it was read in the if and the time the breakpoint got hit.

Comment: @knittl: Yes, i had something like that in mind with #1. Should have been more explicit.

Comment: This is the template generated by VS. I did not change anything. neither I used / manipulated  that property. The value was false before stepping into it.

Comment: Do you guys have any idea on how a method is used as a property and not as a method?